# How to use defined names in an array

Tags: excel, vba

I have a long list of defined cell names in a worksheet. I want to use these in a sub to clear all contents. However, I am unsure if there is a good way to put them all into an array and then delete contents of the array.

I know that I can set variables equal to each defined name and then clear, but this is a very tedious solution since I have a great many defined names to clear:

```
Sub arraySolution()

    Dim variableName As Variant

    variableName = ThisWorkbook.Names("CI_DESC").RefersTo
    Range(variableName).ClearContents

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to clear the contents (values) of all named ranges in the document?

This will do it:

```
Sub ClearValsOfNamedRanges()

    Dim namRng As Name

    For Each namRng In ThisWorkbook.Names
         namRng.RefersToRange.ClearContents
    Next namRng

End Sub
```